# Slickgrid TreeGrid drag and drop - How to get row id and details of the row, on which another row, was dragged & dropped

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, slickgrid

I'm trying to implement drag and drop within slickgrid treegrid.
Basically this structure-

```
Electronics > 
                TV > 
                       LED > SONY
                             LG
                       LCD > SAMSUNG
                             TOSHIBA
```

eg - http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html 
I would like the brands to be moved from one category to another.
I got to the point where I got the row to be drag enabled, and gets the details for the row i'm dragging.
By using the following I can get the row which I dragged -

```
$("#teamGrid").bind("drop", function (e, dd) {
                                   data[dd.row]
                                  }
```

Now, how do I get the details or id of the row where I dropped the drag-row?
Is there an example where drag drop is enabled within the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also if anyone was wondering the code to determine the id from the row being dragged -

```
var dragRow = $(e.target).closest(".ui-widget-content slick-row");
dragId = dragRow.context.offsetParent.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

This is especially important because the default api grid.selectedRows(), gives the wrong result setif the treegrid is collapsed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out -

```
var name = e.target.offsetParent.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = name;
alert(temp.textContent || temp.innerText);
```